# How to convert JSON file to excel?

Tags: json, excel, emeditor

I have a large JSON file around 3gb and I want to convert it to readable excel format. How can I achieve this?

Can I do it via emeditor? It supports JSON but not sure if I can convert that to excel.

Any input is appreciated.
Thanks

For eg:

```
{
  "name": "George Washington",
  "birthday": "February 22, 1732",
  "address": "Mount Vernon, Virginia, United States"
}

{
  "first_name": "George",
  "last_name": "Washington",
  "birthday": "1732-02-22",
  "address": {
    "street_address": "3200 Mount Vernon Memorial Highway",
    "city": "Mount Vernon",
    "state": "Virginia",
    "country": "United States"
  }
}
```

So here I want First Name, Last name, birthday, address all to be csv headers and all the data should be copied under that so that I can have a clean csv file with all the details.

Comment: this [module](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmEditor will not convert JSON to Excel (or CSV) files by itself. However, you can write a macro to convert JSON to CSV files. If you need support on writing a macro, can you write a small JSON sample, and how you want the output CSV look like?

**Updates**

This is a macro for you to convert JSON to CSV. It allows up to only one-deep nested structure of JSON. This macro checks if a delimiter (comma) exists in data but does NOT check if a double quotation mark or new line code exists. I also noticed your JSON data contains syntax errors, and I corrected it.

**Macro** `JsonToCsv.jsee` :

```
function AddStr( s1, s2 )
{
    if( s2.toString().indexOf( ',' ) != -1 ) {
        s2 = '"' + s2 + '"';
    }
    return s1 + s2;
}

sHeading = "";
sBody = "";
document.selection.SelectAll();
var json = JSON.parse(document.selection.Text);
for( property in json ) {
    if( typeof json[property] === 'object' ) {
        for( property2 in json[property] ) {
            if( sHeading.length != 0 ){
                sHeading += ",";
                sBody += ",";
            }
            sHeading = AddStr( sHeading, property2 );
            sBody = AddStr( sBody, json[property][property2] );
        }
    }
    else {
        if( sHeading.length != 0 ){
            sHeading += ",";
            sBody += ",";
        }
        sHeading = AddStr( sHeading, property );
        sBody = AddStr( sBody, json[property] );
    }
}
editor.NewFile();
document.selection.Text = sHeading + "\r\n" + sBody + "\r\n";
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22528);  // switch to CSV mode
```

**Input:**

```
{
  "name": "George Washington",
  "birthday": "February 22, 1732",
  "first_name": "George",
  "last_name": "Washington",
  "birthday": "1732-02-22",
  "address": {
    "street_address": "3200, Mount Vernon Memorial Highway",
    "city": "Mount Vernon",
    "state": "Virginia",
    "country": "United States"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
name,birthday,first_name,last_name,street_address,city,state,country
George Washington,1732-02-22,George,Washington,"3200, Mount Vernon Memorial Highway",Mount Vernon,Virginia,United States
```

You can run this macro after you open your data file. To do this, save this code as, for instance, `JsonToCsv.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your data file, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while your data file is active.

Comment: Yes, can you please check the OP I've edited the post since I can't post proper code in comment section due to formatting issue.

Thanks