# Converting JSON file to CSV using EmEditor? [error with JsonToCsv.jsee]

Tags: python, json, csv, emeditor

I need to convert a large `JSON` to `CSV`, using `EmEditor (Text Editor)`. I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220312/how-to-convert-json-file-to-excel/63251364#63251364) and didn't work for me.

I have an error message says: Syntax error at Line 12

Could anyone look into my codes?

My json sample:

```json
[
      {
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": null,
        "test": true,
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": true,
        "test": true,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": "",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": "null",
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null
      },
      {
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": null,
        "test": true,
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": true,
        "test": true,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": "",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": "null",
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": false,
        "test": "null",
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null,
        "test": null
        }
    ]
```

I'm not sure if the problem originates from my sample JSON format or the macros code.

if a python code can also do the job, is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The syntax error refers to the jsee code in the other answer. It uses the syntax of the new v8 engine. In [Customize Macros](https://www.emeditor.org/en/cmd_macros_customize_macro_options.html), select Use V8 as JavaScript Engine then run the macro.

Your JSON data is invalid as you use the key `"test"` for each entry of the objects. You should use a unique key for each entry. After that, perhaps you could use an online tool like this one https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm if your JSON isn't too long.

Comment: As I said at the beginning, I have a big file, of course I couldn't put everything here, so I made an example similar to it. when using V8 engine i get "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString'" If I have only one part it works but after the syntax it doesn't convert any data

Comment: The macro script in the other answer will not work for the format of the JSON file you have. I'll write a script for you, but your JSON is invalid at the moment. Please fix it to have unique keys. EmEditor can validate your JSON if you go to View > Syntax Checker.